# Automatic form refresh on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that submits a form. I'm trying to get automatic refresh once the submit button is hit.

```
<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="Name" name="name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="Email Address" name="email" type="email" pattern="^[A-Za-z0-9](([_\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)@([A-Za-z0-9]+)(([\.\-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*)\.([A-Za-z]{2,})$"  tabindex="2" required autofocus>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="Phone Number" type="tel" name="phno" tabindex="3" size="10" oninvalid="setCustomValidity('Please fill out this field')" required autofocus >
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <input placeholder="Zip Code" name="zip" type="zip" tabindex="4" size="5"  required autofocus>
</fieldset>

<fieldset>
  <textarea placeholder="Type your message here...." name="msg" tabindex="5" required autofocus></textarea>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
        <input type="submit" class="submit button" id="submit" value="Submit Message" /> <div id="contact-message"></div>
```

Comment: You forgot to include all this in a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to enclose the `<input>`s in a form with an action attribute.

```html
<form action="url/to/handle">
  <fieldset>
    <input placeholder="Name" name="name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
  </fieldset>
  ...
  <input type="submit" class="submit button" id="submit" value="Submit Message" />
</form>
```

Comment: I actually included form but forgot to copy that above. 







 <form method="post" action="/contact.html"  id="contactform" >
    <fieldset> ...
    <fieldset> <input type="submit" class="submit button" id="submit" value="Submit Message" /> <div id="contact-message"></div> <br> <br>
    </fieldset>
     </form>

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this at the end of your submit function:

```
$('form').find("input").val("");
```